# Writing a google sheet to a github repo as json?

Tags: json, google-sheets, svelte

I'm an entry level coder please go easy on me. I'm working with some collaborators on a google sheet. I want to be able to pull in the data from the sheet to json file on my github repo that will populate in a Svelte app.

I've set up [this script](https://thenewstack.io/how-to-convert-google-spreadsheet-to-json-formatted-text/) for sheets so it can generate the sheet as JSON. I click the script button in Sheets and a window pops up with the json.

Wondering if there's a webhook or something that could then pull that json to my svelte app. So when a collaborator edits the sheet I could just run a terminal command to pull it in, or something to that effect.

If anyone has any guidance let me know I'm having trouble knowing what to google. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While google doesn't offer a webhook for this, they do offer [App Script](https://script.google.com/home/start) which would be able to do the functionality you're asking for. If you set the event source to be the spreadsheet and the event type to be "On Change", you would be able to run whatever App Script code you want (including making an http request to an endpoint you control!).

[image]